# How to quickly determine the inverse of elementary matrices?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Say I have an elementary matrix associated with a row operation performed when doing Jordan Gaussian elimination so for example if I took the matrix that added 3 times the 1st row and added it to the 3rd row then the matrix would be the $3\times3$ identity matrix with a $3$ in the first column 3rd row instead of a zero.

Is there a way to quickly determine it's inverse (as in just by looking at it pretty much and without calculating cofactor matrix and transposing it.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The inverses of elementary matrices are described in the properties section of [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. If we show the matrix that adds line $j$ multiplied by a number $\alpha_{ij}$ to line $i$ by $E_{ij}$, then its inverse is simply calculated by $E^{-1} = 2I - E_{ij}$.

Comment: This is long after the event but future readers should beware: this is not the standard use of the symbol $E_{ij}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following approaches:

- **Inversion algorithm**: write using block form $[E|I] → [I| E^{-1}]$ where E denotes the elementary matrix and I the identity one, simply write them one side by side, then perform elementary row operations on E to take it to identity matrix and you will get its inverse in place of I.
- **Inverse elementary row operation**: since you get the elementary matrix from the identity matrix by applying an elementary row operation, to get the inverse of E you have to apply the corresponding inverse row operation to identity matrix.